# What is the recommended way to write modular Keras code?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm struggling to write Keras code that is composable and modular, and I'm wondering if maybe I'm just using the wrong API? What I want is:

1. wrap up keras layers and custom layers together
2. re-use them easily, ideally just like any built in Keras layer
3. saving and loading has to work as well

   - Preferably without the code the roduced it.

I attempted subclassing `Model` but those cannot be saved (?!?) unless:

> serialization is implemented by the author of the subclassed network

I could make change the code to inherit from `Layer` but then the weights do not seem train, even though it runs without any errors

So, what are my options here? links to examples would be the most helpful here.

Comment: I think you need to write a class for your `custom layer` inthereting from `Layer` class. You can check this site. https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/

Comment: @Faruk This issue is the custom Layers containing other existing layers does not work -- it seems the inner layers do not train. Do you know of any working examples where custom layers are nested and can be trained?

Comment: Sadly, no. maybe this search will give you some clue. https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&ei=rVMTXcujGcb5wAKxtJqwDg&q=keras+layer+inside+layer+&oq=keras+layer+inside+layer+&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i203.2567.3160..3252...0.0..1.260.715.0j4j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i19j0i22i30i19j0i22i30.Yi5xAOqd3sI